# Got the wrong value from the console using match

Tags: rust

I have not yet used match so I can't understand it very well. I want to try to write a number in the console, but I got the wrong value from match.

My code:

```rust
    let mut choice = String::new();
    let choice = io::stdin().read_line(&mut choice).unwrap();
    match choice {
        1 => println!("1"),
        2 => println!("2"),
        3 => println!("3"),
        _ => println!("this number doesn't exist"),
    };
```

And the printed value is `2`, but I wrote `1` in the console.

Answer (score 3):

[`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) doesn't return your input; it returns the number of bytes entered (including the newline at the end). You entered `1` followed by a newline, so 2 characters, so you get `2` as the return value. The actual text is stored in the string you passed a mutable reference to.

```rust
let mut choice = String::new();

// Modifies the choice variable in-place.
io::stdin().read_line(&mut choice).unwrap();

// Now choice contains our input, so let's parse it as an integer.
let choice = i32::from_str(&choice).unwrap();
match choice {
  ...
}
```

Comment: ugh, "from_str" isn't found

Comment: and if i use `std::str::from_str` i got an error ```thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }```

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsIwEETv@YopB0gkGgTcHMGxt/bSD4hMspCVEjuy102lim9PnbYBoV7fzs7srAtexjF4gpdaKS9OqRdnu3dxRXLDbIskORt0mk2a4SsBWhJ0QVA1livCAXGDzUUpQ0OaRTmw2eDV1nxm8pCGZumHdqxPLYHNc9/qivKoZTuF15N97kjXZcuG0uU9IcuDGZzu795vdpgtK2sknuZhg4u2fZA1vJ1uXHn02sUeLNAe2sSx0IVc/tfhdj/vd0qdY/UyPiFd/k9FrC9VM29MTwC2OBzRx@bSmqd0sV1k6x@@e@S7me8f@X7m5SOXhj1M6E7kUFvyZiWgT/byq78WyXUct98).

Comment: @Nats I suspect you are adding a newline after the digits which [will](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsIwEETv@YopB0gkGgTcHMGxt/bSD4hMspCVEjuy102lim9PnbYBoV7fzs7srAtexjF4gpdaKS9OqRdnu3dxRXLDbIskORt0mk2a4SsBWhJ0QVA1livCAXGDzUUpQ0OaRTmw2eDV1nxm8pCGZumHdqxPLYHNc9/qivKoZTuF15N97kjXZcuG0uU9IcuDGZzu795vdpgtK2sknuZhg4u2fZA1vJ1uXHn02sUeLNAe2sSx0IVc/tfhdj/vd0qdY/UyPiFd/k9FrC9VM29MTwC2OBzRx@bSmqd0sV1k6x@@e@S7me8f@X7m5SOXhj1M6E7kUFvyZiWgT/byq78WyXUct8k3) give you that error.